# clone method in Lists in Java - is it shallow copy or deep copy?

Tags: list, clone, deep-copy, shallow-copy

as I understand when I am using the clone method given for List or if I use copy constructor for list I need to get a shallow copy of the list:

```
 ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
 a.add(new String("dog"));
 a.add(new String("cat"));
 ArrayList<String> b = new ArrayList<String>(a);
 //ArrayList<String> b = (ArrayList<String>)a.clone();

b.remove(0);
Iterator<String> iter = a.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iter.next());
}
Iterator<String> iter2 = b.iterator();
while(iter2.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(iter2.next());
} 



out put:
dog
cat
cat
```

If b is a shallow copy of a then how come that when I remove an element from b it is not removed from a?

Answer (score 0):

Because `b` is a separate list, which was created by copying the items in `a`.

The fact that it's a shallow copy means that the items inside of `a` are not cloned; they refer to the same objects. A deep copy would mean that both the list and the items inside the list would be cloned. In both cases though, the list itself is cloned, so they are now two different objects.